# Leak in CGBitmapContextCreate

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

Trying to find the leak in my code I removed all the thing that did not matter, leaving the following code:

```
static int last_memory = 0;

void report_memory(NSString *name) {
    struct task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(),
                                   TASK_BASIC_INFO,
                                   (task_info_t)&info,
                                   &size);
    if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
        int change = (int)info.resident_size - last_memory;
        NSLog(@"%@ >>> Memory in use: %u (change: %d Kb)", name, info.resident_size, change/1024 );
        last_memory = info.resident_size;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
    }
}

- (CGContextRef) createBitmapContextOfSize:(CGSize) size {
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (size.width * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height);

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (bitmapData == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Memory not allocated!");
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        return NULL;
    }
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     size.width,
                                     size.height,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing (context,NO);
    if (context== NULL) {
        free (bitmapData);
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        NSLog (@"Context not created!");
        return NULL;
    }
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    return context;
}

- (IBAction) clickButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    report_memory(@"begin");
    NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

    report_memory(@"image_created");

    CGContextRef myBitmapContext = [self createBitmapContextOfSize:CGSizeMake(256, 256)];
    if (!myBitmapContext){
        return;
    }
    report_memory(@"bitmap_context_created");
    CGContextDrawImage(myBitmapContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, 256, 256), image.CGImage);
    report_memory(@"draw_image");
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(myBitmapContext);
    report_memory(@"image_context_created");
    CGContextRelease(myBitmapContext);
    report_memory(@"bitmap_context_released");
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
    report_memory(@"image_created");
    CGImageRelease(ref);
    report_memory(@"image_context_released");   
    imageView.image = result;
    report_memory(@"image_assigned");   
}
```

("test" is 256x256 JPEG image).
The console showed the following after a few clicks:

```
begin >>> Memory in use: 18866176 (change: -12 Kb)
image_created >>> Memory in use: 18870272 (change: 4 Kb)
bitmap_context_created >>> Memory in use: 18870272 (change: 0 Kb)
draw_image >>> Memory in use: 19140608 (change: 264 Kb)
image_context_created >>> Memory in use: 19140608 (change: 0 Kb)
bitmap_context_released >>> Memory in use: 19140608 (change: 0 Kb)
image_created >>> Memory in use: 19140608 (change: 0 Kb)
image_context_released >>> Memory in use: 19140608 (change: 0 Kb)
image_assigned >>> Memory in use: 19140608 (change: 0 Kb)
```

A net loss of 256Kb per click (equal to 256x256x4). The same trend could be seen in the allocations performance tool. Everything pointing to the CGBitmapContext not being released. I just don't see what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the CGBitmapContextCreate allocate the memory itself by providing NULL as the first argument (bitmapData). That frees you from managing your memory allocation - which you're not freeing at the moment.